# A small question on probability about darts

Tags: probability

Let's say that there is a dart board with countable infinitely many points on it. We have a dart with us and we select a point on the dart board. Now what is the probability that we hit that particular point that we have chosen,given that the event of throwing the dart takes place?
The size of the dart is same as the size of the point

Comment: How thick is the dart? How good is the thrower?

Comment: The dart is as thick as the point and the thrower is a pro in this

Comment: In the idealized case, when we model the dart board as a (part of) the euclidean plane, and points are mathemathical points, the probability is zero.  If you want the non-idealized case, we need much more information.

Comment: But if it is 0 then it means the event didn't take place @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: No, that is false: if $X$ has a standard normal distribution, then we have $P(X=\pi)=0$, and the same holds for **any** particular real number choosen in advance!  But, the variable must have some value! The point is that the sample space is **uncountable**. Do you know what that means?

Comment: The sample space is infinity therefore the probability will be $1/{\infinity}$@kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: But that doesn't make sense to me@kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: I have done a change in the question and have changed the statement to countable infinitely many points @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: Obviously it will be very small. How small? $1 \over {number  of  points}$. And the total number of points is countably infinite.

Answer (score 2):

For throwing a dart at a dartboard, you would usually say that the probability that the dart lands in a particular measurable region is proportional to the area of that region.  There is no requirement that $P(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i)=\sum_{i\in I} P(A_i)$ for uncountable index sets $I$ -- just for countable ones.  So it's fine that the probability of hitting any particular point is exactly zero; you can still have nonzero probability of hitting a finite region.